# how to open a 'csv file' like 'url launcher' in Flutter

Tags: csv, flutter, launch

i converted  list into File of .csv extension then
 tried **OpenFile.open** and ended up with error `No permissions found in manifest for: 2`, tried **canLaunch** and ended up with error `name.csv exposed beyond app through Intent.getData(), Failed to handle method call`

so how to open that csv file in any 3rd part application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
and make sure you have a file `/sdcard/Download/sample.csv`, see picture below 
You also need CSV Viewer installed in your Emulator 
code snippet

```
    final filePath = '/sdcard/Download/sample.csv';
    print('${filePath}');
    final message = await OpenFile.open(filePath);
```

working demo

[image]

device file explorer

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _openResult = 'Unknown';

  Future<void> openFile() async {
    //final filePath = '/sdcard/Download/sample.pdf';
    final filePath = '/sdcard/Download/sample.csv';
    print('${filePath}');
    final message = await OpenFile.open(filePath);

    setState(() {
      _openResult = message;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('open result: $_openResult\n'),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Tap to open file'),
                onPressed: openFile,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: geting 'D/permissions_handler( 6242): No permissions found in manifest for: 2',
any idea about this exception .......!!
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> those are my permissions in manifest also i'm sure my application has access to storage too

Comment: Did you copy paste run my full code and get this exception?

Comment: You do not need to modify manifest with my full code. open_file will ask you to do that.

Comment: you're right, took off permissions validation and made hit directly.... it worked ;)